# Как отредактировать отложенное сообщение?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Копированием скидываю сообщение в отложку

```py
schedule_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 10, 23, 59, 1)
message_data = send.copy(channel_list[channel_id], schedule_date=schedule_date)
```

Но при помощи метода `edit_message_text` не могу его отредактировать.

```py
message_id = message_data.id
message_text = "blablabla"
client.edit_message_text(channel_list[channel_id], message_id, message_text, 
disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Отвечает ошибкой о неверном `id` сообщения.
В документации не нашел решения данной проблемы. Хотя в офф.клиенте телеграма можно редактировать отложенные сообщения. Есть возможность это как-то сделать именно через редактирование в отложке или такого функционала не предусмотрено?